How to use Spline Viewer in Angular 18 project
I can use Spline in my Angular project using Code Export, but non-step Scroll supposedly only works with the viewer.
import { SplineViewer } from '@splinetool/viewer';

and
imports: [SplineViewer],

Show an error popper:

Component imports must be standalone components, directives, pipes, or must be NgModules.(-992012)

Will there be native support for Angular? Does anyone know how to use Spline Viewer in Angular?
I tried making a separate component for SplineViewer and import it there; however, makes sense, SplineViewer still wasn't a standalone component.

With AngularJS 18 I followed the steps in the NPM documentation.
TIP: make sure to add the 'canvas' inside a 'div' like
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <canvas id="canvas3d"></canvas>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

and in the component .ts file (good thing you already created a separate component for your design)
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Application } from '@splinetool/runtime';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-robot',
 standalone: true,
 imports: [],
 templateUrl: './robot.component.html',
 styleUrl: './robot.component.css'
})
export class RobotComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
 // make sure you have a canvas in the body
 const canvas: any = document.getElementById('canvas3d');

 // start the application and load the scene
 const spline = new Application(canvas);
 spline.load('https://example.com/<Your code goes here>/scene.splinecode');
 }
}

Additionally, you might have to adjust the size of your canvas in the component's .css file as
#canvas3d {
 min-height: 400px;
 max-height: 400px;
 max-width: fit-content;
}

In the parent component, import the spline/new component and use the tag
<div class="container mt-4 mb-4" *ngIf="postsArray && 
postsArray.length == 0">
 <div class="row">
    <h4 class="text-center my-2">New Content Coming Soon...</h4>
    <app-robot></app-robot>
</div>

